# iOS SDK for logging to Social Media like Facebook, Twitter, linkedin,google +?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am developing new iPhone app in which i have provide users a option to login to application using Facebook,twitter,linked in and Google+.

Can some please let me know do we have any single API/sdk which supports all the social Media because its easy to implement and will not be confused with using different API/sdk's.

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it, ''mob'' offers services in China.
It integrates the world's leading social media, including Facebook Google+ Twitter ...
To give you a link, it supports English [enter link description here](http://sharesdk.mob.com/en)
But I do use Facebook, Twitter to login is very simple, official API written in great detail.